# Adding Chapter - seq number to Figure caption

Tags: captions

Here is my subroutine:
Sub InsertExhibitLabel()
'
' InsertExhibitLabel Macro
' Place cursor on line below an exhibit (before the caption title) and run to insert exhibit field.
'   Before: "|Caption Title"
'   After:  "Figure [Chapter-#]. Caption Title"
'
'

```
'Insert numbered FigureLabel
Selection.InsertCaption label:="Figure", TitleAutoText:="InsertCaption1", _
Title:="", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0


'Set to Caption style
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Caption")

'Add period and space
Selection.TypeText Text:=". "
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean exactly with a "Chapter-seq" number?